# VC++ regular expression match long string

Tags: c++, regex

I have the followig code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::tr1::regex rx("(\\w+)(\\.|_)?(\\w*)@(\\w+)(\\.(\\w+))+");
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin,s);
    if(regex_match(s.begin(),s.end(),rx))
    {
        std::cout << "Matched!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It is working well if regex is something like `"myemail@domain.com"` but if I try `"myemail@domain.com:anothermail@domain.com:useless string:blah blah"`
it fails!

What can I do to match the valid strings (eventually print the found string out, only the matched part not all string)?

I succeed somehow, but with some REGEX patterns it fails:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string str("mymail@yahoo.com;lslsls;myemail@gmail.com");
    std::tr1::regex rx("[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}");
    std::tr1::sregex_iterator first(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);
    std::tr1::sregex_iterator last;

    for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) 
    {
        std::cout << "[Email] => " << it->str(1) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

here instead getting `mymail@yahoo.com` and `myemail@gmail.com` I get `yahoo.c` and `gmail.`

Comment: forgot to add `"()"` to my REGEX, solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regex_match`is used to check a string to an exact pattern.

Either you use `regex_search`, depending on your requirements or your pattern have to cover all possibilities. 
Take a look at [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx)

Comment: You're right! regex_search does the trick and works! Do you have any idea how can I do and print out the matched string? Like print out "myemail@yahoo.com" from "myemail@domain.com:anothermail@domain.com:useless string:blah blah" and strip the not matched text?